# How to find the default atol and rtol for scipy.integrate.ode?

Tags: python, scipy, default, ode

How do I find the default parameters in `scipy.integrate.ode`? Specifically, `atol` and `rtol` in integrator `dopri5`? Parameters can be set with the `set_integrator` method, but I can’t see any way to query it find out what it’s been using if I do not set them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only way to find out is looking into [the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/_ode.py). There, starting with lines 966 (as of now), you’ll find:

```
class dopri5(IntegratorBase):

    […]

    def __init__(self,
                 rtol=1e-6, atol=1e-12,
                 nsteps=500,
                 max_step=0.0,
                 […]
                 ):
```

So, `dopri`’s default absolute tolerance is 10⁻¹² and its default relative tolerance is 10⁻⁶. (Yes, this should be documented.)

Comment: Nice. I really should have thought of that.

Comment: @PeterB: Still, you shouldn’t need to do this. We can be happy that these parameters are set on the Python level and are not buried in some ported Fortran routine.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft  How about creating an issue for this over at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source for ode() it looks like the integrator of an ode that you have instantiated can be inspected by doing the following for example:

```
r = ode(f)
print('atol:', r._integrator.atol)
print('rtol:', r._integrator.rtol)
```

Comment: This should be the excepted answer, because it answers how to get the values from the generated python objects and not by looking into source code that could change from version to version.